# Using Skype URI can I localize the text of the Callbutton?

Tags: uri, skype, skype-uri.js

I'm using the generated Skype buttons found at http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages using skype-uri.js 
The Skype button turns up fine, but the text is "Call" and I would like another text here (Ring).
Couldn't find a property for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I came to the conclusion that you can't, it's not supported atm.
Answering this question just if someone else is looking for the answer to this.